# Excel slicers does not hide items without data when filtering using timeline

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have some pivottables, slicers and one timeline connected together. In the pivottable the timeline filters correctly.

I have set up the slicers with "hide items with no data". But when I filter on dates using the timeline, the slicers shows items with no data within the timeframe set in the timeline. Is it possible to solved this in a simple way? My dataset has 200k+ rows, so I don`t think using vba to loop through all rows within the timeframe and hide the items without data would be a good solution with regards to perfomance.

Comment: Just add the data you're counting/summing/whatever into the filter field of the pivot table, and when you have filtered by dates, filter by blanks again.

Comment: There are no blanks to filter out.